# Insert image with html+=

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that inserts a selected album and selected title into a description box, I would then like to insert the corresponding artwork with that song. However using html+= doesn't seem to work. The first two html+= are fine.

```
 function createSongInfo(album_index, song_length) {


var html = "";

html += "You have selected album: " + albums[album_index].title;
html += "<br>You have selected song: " + albums[album_index].tracks[song_length].title;
html +=<img src='"files/artwork/"+albums[album_index].artwork+".jpg"' alt="Album Artwork">;

writeIframe("all_details_frame", html);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a proper string instead of whatever that is?

Comment: Yes I've fixed it thanks to Seckin, I wasn't sure if my quotes would work like that, I realise now I should have used the slash technique. @Chris what do you mean  by a proper string?

Comment: See any of the answers below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *wrap* the string to append in quotes, and *escape* the other quotes in it.

Change the line

```
html +=<img src='"files/artwork/"+albums[album_index].artwork+".jpg"' alt="Album Artwork">;
```

to

```
html += "<img src=\"files/artwork/" + albums[album_index].artwork + ".jpg\" alt=\"Album Artwork\" />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are misplaced. The single quote should be at the start of the html section and it should close at the end of the html section.

SO syntax highlighting should have helped you identify the problem.